# Solidity: call() with bubbling the revert reason

Tags: solidity, revert

Consider the following Solidity code:

```
        (bool success, ) = address(_token).call(
            abi.encodePacked(
                _RECEIVE_WITH_AUTHORIZATION_SELECTOR,
                receiveAuthorization
            )
        );
```

This uses [call()](https://solidity-by-example.org/call/) for an external contract call.

However, as we know, `call` does not bubble any revert reason, and thus loses important debug information.

Is there a way to do call-equivalent but directly raise any revert as a passthrough instead of absorbing and losing the revert message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code snippet that checks if a call reverts, loads the revert string message if true and raises it correctly.

**Side note:** Using `abi.encodePacked` can lead to incorrect input encoding if you are using solidity types < 32 bytes (i.e. address, uint8 ...). Instead use `abi.encodeWithSelector` for this end.

```
    (bool success, bytes memory data) = address(_token).call(
        abi.encodeWithSelector(
            _RECEIVE_WITH_AUTHORIZATION_SELECTOR,
            receiveAuthorization
        )
    );

    if(!success) {
        assembly{
            let revertStringLength := mload(data)
            let revertStringPtr := add(data, 0x20)
            revert(revertStringPtr, revertStringLength)
        }
    }
```

However I would discourage using assembly or even the call() method overall. Instead use interfaces for cleaner, easier and more readable code that handles these aspects:

```
interface ITokenAuth {
    function receiveAuthorization(bool _auth) external;
}

contract Example {
    function callMe(address _token, bool _auth) external {
       ITokenAuth(_token).receiveAuthorization(_auth);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In this case it is related to EIP-3009, the example code was directly from the spec. It's using `call()` passthrough of parameters, because it simplifies the process a lot (and likely saves tons of gas.) Here is the spec https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/3010